# Secure HLS AES-128 key URI

Tags: node.js, angular, bitmovin-player

I encrypted video by HLS AES-128 by using the apple tool,
below is my m3u8 file

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://xxxxx.com/api/xxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.key"
#EXTINF:10, 
#EXT-X-BITRATE:658
8ce9e1ef-4b15-4d22-b2dc-c7278757ffb5_0.ts
#EXTINF:10, 
#EXT-X-BITRATE:1798
8ce9e1ef-4b15-4d22-b2dc-c7278757ffb5_1.ts
#EXTINF:1,  
#EXT-X-BITRATE:620
8ce9e1ef-4b15-4d22-b2dc-c7278757ffb5_2.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

The key URI is my API endpoint URL.. from the API I will be getting the key.

but whenever I copy-paste the key URI (https://xxxxx.com/api/xxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.key) in the browser, the key gets downloaded.

how to pass header authorization whenever a player requests the key URI.

or is there is any way to secure the Key URI?

I am playing a video by Bitmovin player(Nodejs), can we pass the header authorization for the key request URI?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

One common way of securing web APIs is to use [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/introduction) (JWTs) and to send them to the API using the [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) HTTP request header.

As for the Bitmovin Player Web SDK (of which I am a developer), HTTP headers can be added to requests using the [preprocessHttpRequest](https://bitmovin.com/docs/player/api-reference/web/web-sdk-api-reference-v8#/player/web/8/docs/interfaces/core_network.networkconfig.html#preprocesshttprequest) method of the Network API. For example, passing a JWT auth token to the API for HLS key requests could be done the following way:

```
const token = 'your-jwt-token';
const playerConfig = {
  key: 'your-key',
  network: {
    preprocessHttpRequest: (type, request) => {
      // Only add the `Authorization` header to HLS key requests
      if (type === bitmovin.player.HttpRequestType.KEY_HLS_AES) {
        // Add the `Authorization` header containing the JWT to the request
        request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
      }

      return Promise.resolve(request);
    }
  }
};

const player = new bitmovin.player.Player(document.getElementById('player'), playerConfig);
```

You don't have to use JWTs - you can transmit arbitrary data to the API using the `Authorization` header. However, using JWTs is more secure as those tokens are usually generated by a trusted source (like [Google's OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect)) and are signed to prevent any modifications. If you want to use JWTs for authentication, your API would have to provide an endpoint to acquire them.